# Convergent subsequence of sum of sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let's consider vector spaces $V_A, V_B$ and $V$ and that every sequence $(a_n) \subseteq V_A \subseteq V$ and $(b_n) \subseteq V_B \subseteq V$ have convergent subsequences.

Then, has every sequence $(a_n + b_n)$ convergent subsequences as well?

Comment: Why fails in the argument: "fix any $(a_n)_n,(b_n)_n$; let $(a_{\phi(n)})_n$ be a convergence subsequence of the former; consider now the sequence $(b_{\phi(n)})_n$: it has a converging subsequence  $(b_{\phi(\psi(n))})_n$. So now, both  $(a_{\phi(\psi(n))})_n$ and  $(b_{\phi(\psi(n))})_n$ converge, so  $(a_{\phi(\psi(n))}+b_{\phi(\psi(n))})_n$ does as well"?

Comment: Sorry, "Why"  -> "What" in the above.

Comment: No. Consider $V_{A} = V_{B} = V = \mathbb{R}$. Let $(a_n) = (1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, \ldots), (b_n) = (0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, \ldots)$. Then $(a_n + b_n) = (1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, \ldots)$.

Comment: arggghhh, too bad ;). But thank you both!

Comment: @AJY I may be missing something -- how is it the case that *every sequence of $V_B$ (say) has a convergent subsequence*? for instance, the subsequence $(1,2,3,\dots)\subseteq V_B$ of $(b_n)_n$ is a sequence of $V_B$. Unless I misunderstood the assumption?

Comment: No real vector space with the standard norm topology has the property that *every* sequence has a convergent subsequence (this is equivalent to compactness). I read the assumption as saying both $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ in particular had convergent subsequences. We might rephrase the question as, "Does the family of sequences in $V$ with convergent subsequences form a vector space?", that is, is it closed under scalar multiplication (trivially so) and addition (as seen, no). But of course OP could clarify.

Comment: Yes, I think the OP should clarify -- as it reads (and whether this is vacuous or not), the question does state "every sequence [...] have convergent subsequences" (which is grammatically problematic, but has a seemingly clear interpretation).

Comment: As AJY mentioned, I wanted to know, if the family of sequences in V with convergent subsequences forms a vector space. Unfortunately it doesn't, but thank you for the easy example.

Obriareos.